# custom input function, weird '?' appended at the end of the string

Tags: c, input

I picked up programing not long ago. I'm trying to create a function to get a string from the user (for practice sake). my getString() function seems to do it jobs, but if the input string is too long (more than 17 characters to be specific), a weird "?" is added to my string. Don't know where did I messed up, I've been looking into it for quite sometimes, here's my code

```
char* getString(void)
{
    /* how large is the buffer */
    unsigned int capacity = 32;
    /* growable buffer to store string */
    char* buffer = malloc(capacity * sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    /* how many characters are actually there in the buffer */
    unsigned int n = 0;
    int c; // character read or EOF

    while((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        // if there's enough space in buffer -> store c into buffer, continue to next loop
        if (n + 1 >= capacity)
        {
            capacity *= 2;
            char* temp = realloc(buffer, capacity * sizeof(char));
            if(temp == NULL)
            {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
            }
            buffer = temp;
        }
        // store c to reallocated buffer
        buffer[n++] = c;
    }

    if (n == 0 && (c == EOF))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // terminate string with '\0'
    buffer[++n] = '\0';
    puts(buffer);
    // remove blank space after '\0'
    buffer = realloc(buffer, (n+1) * sizeof(char));

    // return buffer
    return buffer;
}
```

Test program:

```
Pls gimme a string
12345678901234567890
You gave me this string: "12345678901234567890?", which is 21 chars long
```

Comment: Consider the simple case where `fgetc()` immediately returns `EOF`. Then consider what value `n` will have when you write the `'\0'` to the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
buffer[++n] = '\0';
```

When the loop ends the value of `n` is already correct and where you should put the terminator. Incrementing it once more will put the terminator one step beyond the data you have read into the memory.